# Saber cuando ha pasado una semana con DateTime en dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Flutter que actualiza cierta información cuando pasa una semana. Estamos hablando de una semana en dias desde el lunes hasta el domingo, y no de 7 dias desde que se instala la aplicación o algo así.

Lo que necesito es saber cuando ha pasado esa semana, es decir, cuando llegue el lunes a las 00:00 se tiene que actualizar la información al ejecutar la aplicación y comprobarse dicha condición.

Estoy barajando métodos guardando fechas en las shared preferences, pero no sé de que forma podría compararlas para conseguir lo que quiero (mi conocimiento en DateTime es por ahora limitado).

Algo que estoy probando es esto:

```
void SetDateDiff() {
  DateTime x = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 8));
  DateTime y = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7));

  Duration diff = compare(x, y);

  print("dias:");
  print(diff.inDays);

}

Duration compare(DateTime x, DateTime y) {
  return Duration(
      microseconds:
          (x.microsecondsSinceEpoch - y.microsecondsSinceEpoch).abs());
}
```

Donde he observado que cuando la fecha x se pasa de la y, el resultado de la comparación es 0. Y esto me da una idea de que tendría que saber cuantos dias faltan desde la fecha actual hasta el domingo. ¿Que enfoque le daríais vosotros? Es un problema sencillo sobre el papel, pero sin controllar DateTime no se me ocurren muchos métodos por ahora.

**EDIT**: Pongo el siguiente caso de uso para que se entienda mejor:
La app debe permitir enviar cierto número de datos por semana a la BBDD, algo así como una app tipo Tinder en la que podemos dar un numero determinado de likes cada 24 horas. Pero en este caso, sustituimos esas 24 horas por una semana, de lunes a domingo. Por tanto, la aplicación debe detectar al ejecutarse que, si se ha llegado al lunes a las 00:00, el contador de datos que se pueden enviar debe reiniciarse.

Comment: no entendí muy bien que es lo que quieres, que cada lunes se actualice la info? sin importar que día instaló? que pasa si solo abre la app el miercoles o jueves? y el lunes ni la toca?

Comment: Es justo eso, cuando abre la app, si ha pasado una semana, sin importar la ultima vez que la abrió, se tiene que actualizar una información. Actualizo la pregunta principal con un ejemplo.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es guardar la fecha inicial como una preferencia de usuario para luego ir comparando las demás fechas o puedes guardarla directamente en la base de datos que manejes, para luego consultar y comparar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear una función que se ejecute cada vez que se abra la aplicación y verificar si es una nueva semana y actualizar la información.

```
void init() async {
    final now = DateTime.now();

    //Obtener las preferencias
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Obtener fecha de última actualización de la información
    final lastUpdateString = preferences.getString('last_update');

    //Comprobar si es la primera vez que se abre la aplicación
    if (lastUpdateString != null) {
      final lastUpdate = DateTime.parse(lastUpdateString);
      final diff = now.difference(lastUpdate).inDays;
      //Aquí compruebas si han pasado más de 7 días o si la fecha al abrir la aplicación
      //y la fecha de última actualización no están en la misma semana
      if (diff > 7 || diff > now.weekday - lastUpdate.weekday) {
        //TODO (Actualizar la información)
        ...
        //Estableces la fecha actual como fecha de última actualización
        preferences.setString('last_update', now.toString());
      }
   } else {
      //TODO (Actualizar información por primera vez)
      //Estableces la fecha actual como fecha de última actualización
      preferences.setString('last_update', now.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido.

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime fecha1 = DateTime.parse("2023-02-27");
DateTime fecha2 = Datetime.now();
Duration diff = fecha2.difference(fecha1);
if(diff.inDays == 7){
// TODO: Do something
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, por favor agrega una explicación de cómo tu código soluciona el problema de OP. ;)